# get constraints of view

Tags: ios, swift

How to get leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints of a UIView, as shown in screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do you mean how to get them in the code? Please be more specific

Comment: yes I want to get it in code

Comment: You can even connect them as `IBOutlet`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its better and *easier* to set an identifier for the constraint, as shown in screenshot below, and use following

```
if let topConstraint = button.constraints.first(where: { $0.identifier == "topConstraint" }) {
    ... use topConstraint
}
```

Another way:

```
if let topConstraint = button.constraints.first(where: { ($0.firstAttribute == .top && $0.firstItem === button) || ($0.secondAttribute == .top && $0.secondItem === button) }) {
    ... use topConstraint
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with 3 ways

1. With attribute

```
{view}.constraints.filter { $0.firstAttribute == .leading }
```

2. With Idenetifier, You can give identifier to constraint from storyboard and getted as follows

```
{view}.constraints.filter { $0.identifier == "your identifier" }
```

3. You cen set constraint's outlet in page